# A question related to the existence of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

Is it possible to construct a function $g$ which is analytic on an open set containing the closed unit disc such that $g(z)=(\Im (z))^{2023}$, for all $z$ in the boundary of the unit disc?

I'm pretty much stuck on this problem and not quite sure how to proceed. Any help/hint will be very useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\text{im}(z)=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}$ and on the unit circle, $\overline{z}=\frac{1}{z}$ (for a circle of radius $r$, $\overline{z}=\frac{r^2}{z}$).

Comment: And so due to the Max Modulus principle the maximum of $|g|$ must be in the boundary but in $z=1$ $g(z)=0$. So you have a contradiction. You could use the null function but that's trivial

Comment: @tac How having at zero somewhere contradicts anything

Comment: @reuns the Max Modulus principle. Either $g$ is constant or has to be less than the values it takes in its boundary of the region its defined.

Comment: @tac Try with $f(z)=z-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is that any (nonconstant) analytic function that is real on the unit circle, must have a singularity (which we can make a pole) either inside the unit circle or on the unit circle itself, so the answer to the question is negative; here, for example, $f(z)=((z-1/z)/2i)^{2023}$ works with precisely a pole at the origin; the proof is very easy by the open property of analytic functions.

Let $f$ analytic in the unit disc, continuous and real on the unit circle; then $f(\mathbb D)=U$ a bounded domain in the plane and $f(\partial \mathbb D)=K$ a compact, connected real set, so a closed interval. But (because $f$ is an open map) $\partial U \subset f(\partial \mathbb D)=K$ which means that $U$ is unbounded and that is a contradiction.

If we allow poles inside the unit disc, or we allow $f$ on the unit circle to take values in $\mathbb R \cup \infty$ (and be continuous in the extended sense) then we get such examples easily as noted.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Thank you.

Comment: happy to be of help